# Android Volley String Request not sending POST Data to user database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-volley

I am writing an android app to interact with a user database on a live server. I'm currently working on a 'register user' activity, which is supposed to simply add a user to the database, based on information they enter in an edit text field.

I am Using Android's Volley Library to accomplish this, using a simple String Request. The request is then added to a request queue. I am able to connect and get a response from the server, but when I attempt to update the database (add a user) nothing happens.

I understand that while using method=POST (which my server does), one must override the getParams() method specifying Key/Value pairs (where KEY is the post data from the php script and the value is the new data.)

Ive tried implementing my request queue as a singleton class, creating a custom header, and even tried modifying volley's method from POST to 'DEPRECATED_GET_OR_POST' with no luck. If someone can tell me what i'm doing wrong or what's missing id greatly appreciate it.

Here's my code:

```
//url to the registration page (on the server)
private static final String Register_URL = "http://www.wupx.com/arcums/profile/register.php";

//key values (these are the values in the DB)
public static final String Key_Username = "username";
public static final String Key_Realname = "name";
public static final String Key_Password = "password2";
public static final String Key_Email = "email";

//declare the editText field & Button
private EditText editTextUsername;
private EditText editTextName;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private EditText editTextPassword2;
private Button buttonRegister;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    //reference editText fields and buttons
    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRealName);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextPassword2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswordAgain);
    buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);


    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();//calls the registerUser method.
        }


    });
}

//method to add user to the arcums database
private void registerUser() {
    //print textview contents to logcat (debugging)
    Log.d("log message", "entering register User method");



    //values passed in from the user
    final String Username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Password2 = editTextPassword2.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Register_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    // put a toast here
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, R.string.register_response , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error toast
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, R.string.register_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){

            //returns a hashmap with key value pairs
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(Key_Username, Username);
                params.put(Key_Realname, Name);
                params.put(Key_Password, Password2);
                params.put(Key_Email, Email);
                return params;
            }

    };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

and here's a screenshot of my DB values in php myadmin:
[DB values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYN0d.png)

note that not all fields need to be filled out in order to be added to the database- just name, username, email, and password.

the server itself has no GUI so i'm unable to post the PHP code at the moment. I hope someone can help with the information given!

Comment: Can you see if your php script recives the values from volley?

Comment: How would I go about that? I'd need a way to output those values in my oRresponse, right?

Comment: The response from the server is just the registration form. the script actually uses a button to trigger the insertion of a new user. Im wondering if this is actually being triggered when i send the request?